# Creating another seekbar using the current one doesn't work

Tags: java, android, recursion, android-seekbar

Suppose I have a seekbar with min value 0 and max value 100
when the user stops the seekbar at any value let's say suppose 50 I want another seekbar to appear with the min value of 51 and max value of 100
And I implemented the functionality but when the second seekbar appear on the screen it doesn't respond when I try to move the slider although it creates another seekbar but that too doesn't allow me to move the slider

here is my code

```
public class seekBar {
    public seekBar(int min , int max , Context context , Activity activity){
        SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(context);
        Button minButton = new Button(context);
        minButton.setText(min+"");
        Button maxButton = new Button(context);
        maxButton.setText(max+"");
        LinearLayout hLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        hLinearLayout.addView(minButton);
        hLinearLayout.addView(seekBar);
        hLinearLayout.addView(maxButton);
        hLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
        layoutParams.setMargins(30, 30, 30, 30);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        seekBar.setMax(max);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            seekBar.setMin(min);
        }



        LinearLayout linearLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        linearLayout.addView(hLinearLayout);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                maxButton.setText(""+progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                minButton.setText("X");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                minButton.setText(min+"");

                int newMax = seekBar.getProgress();
                seekBar.setMax(newMax);
//                createSeekBar(newMax+1 , max);
                new seekBar(newMax , max , context , activity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```